# passing form control value to custom validator angular reactive form

Tags: forms, angular, angular-reactive-forms, custom-validators, angular-validation

There is a custom validator which takes a value as a parameter and checks if the belonged control value is equal to that parameter value or not. the form is `reactive form`, and the value which should be checked is existing controls value  (fisrstname, lastname and email) in form.

the problem is that when the form is created none of the controls (fisrstname, lastname and email) have value, so null will be sent to validation function and then validation does not work, How should this situation be handled?? I am thinking of `custom async validator` but do not know how to implement and if it is right to think about.

**custom validator**

```
public static specialNameValidator(name: string): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} => {
        if (control.value) {
            return name === control.value.toLowerCase()
                       ? {['specialname'] : {value: control.value}}
                       : null;
        }
    };
}
```

**form creation**

```
private createForm(): void {
        this.signupFrom = this.formBuilder.group({
            firstname: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
            lastname: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
            country: new FormControl(null/*, Validators.required*/),
            email: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
            password: new FormControl(null,
                [Validators.required,
                PasswordValidation.NoSpace(),
                PasswordValidation.specialNameValidator(this.model.email),
                PasswordValidation.specialNameValidator(this.model.first_name),
                PasswordValidation.specialNameValidator(this.model.last_name)
                ]),
            passwordconfirm: new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
        },
        // add a validator for the whole group
        { validator: PasswordValidation.PasswordMatch('password', 
          'passwordconfirm')});
    }
```

Comment: you need to add check for the controls being touched and dirty inside your validator function. Try this: `if (control && control.dirty && control.touched && !control.valid)`.

Comment: is your validation working after the initial `null` scenario? (trying to identify if that is the real issue here)

Comment: @amal, its initial value is null regarding to empty form at initial state, when form is filled, `this.model.last_name` has value but the validation does not track the new value

Comment: I don't see from your code how `this.model.last_name` is related to the `formGroup` or the `formControl`s you have in your form (except from being used for validations). Could you show/explain how that variable is used in your component? Is it expected to change with the value of the `lastname` `formControl`?